# Questions about ChannelTrafficShapingHandler

Tags: netty

What's the expected behavior when using ChannelTrafficShapingHandler? or what's the difference between using it with not using it? I didn't see any difference between them with Netty-4.0.21.

Comment: It's probably a bug? I'd say `ChannelTrafficShapingHandler` has been experimental at best since 4, and we need a lot of polishing in that area.

Comment: @trustin you are right, I have send a pull request for this